# How do i convert angularjs attrs into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes

Trying to figure out a good way to convert an unknown quantity of attributes passed into an angular directive into an array for odata purposes.

```
<my-directive pagenum="3" itemcount="40" name="Thompson" something="blah" ></my-directive>
```

..My directive .js file contains so far

```
 link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    //pseudo code//
    var attrArray = {};
    foreach (attrs.$attr as someattrname){
       attrArray[someattrname] = attrs.someattrname; // Of course this doesnt work.
    }
    scope.runListQuery(attrArray);  // they get serialized into an odata url in here
 },
 controller:['$scope','myDataFactory', function($scope,myDataFactory) {

    $scope.runListQuery = function(attrs) {
      myDataFactory.getQuery(attrs).success(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;
      });
    };
```

Comment: That would probably work if you declare `attrArray` as an array instead of an object. Try `var attrArray = [];`

Comment: @Blackhole Makes sense actually, that sub object gives you just the attributes that were put on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that does basically what you want. You can use this to get where you are trying to go.

```
function linkFunc(scope, elem, attrs) {
  for (var property in attrs.$attr) {
    if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      console.log(property);        // The attribute name
      console.log(attrs[property]); // The attribute value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Realized I can't use `angular.forEach` here because the keys and values are coming from two different places.